# can't download new packages and updates

Tags: system-installation

```
dpkg: error processing package sessioninstaller (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libxapian22
 zeitgeist-core
 zeitgeist-datahub
 zeitgeist
 activity-log-manager
 activity-log-manager-control-center
 python-xapian
 apt-xapian-index
 rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist
 unity-lens-applications
 sessioninstaller
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please add some more information than just the error message? When did this occur? What did you do before?

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and type:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
```

I think it will do the job...  :)